# Trigger issue - firing only for last row

Tags: plsql, oracle11g

I have the following trigger definition and the issue is it's only firing on the last row which is updated but not on the previous rows.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER APPS.cx_iby_trxn_summary_au
AFTER UPDATE
ON ar.ar_receivable_applications_all
REFERENCING NEW AS NEW OLD AS OLD
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (
NEW.APPLIED_CUSTOMER_TRX_ID IS NOT NULL AND
NEW.STATUS = 'APP' AND
NEW.DISPLAY = 'Y'
  )
DECLARE 
   vn_cash_receipt_id  NUMBER := -1;  
BEGIN 

insert into cx_log values('Cash Receipt :' || :NEW.RECEIVABLE_APPLICATION_ID);

BEGIN

    SELECT acra.cash_receipt_id
      INTO vn_cash_receipt_id
      FROM ar_cash_receipts_all acra,
           iby_trxn_summaries_all itsa              
     WHERE     acra.cash_receipt_id = :NEW.CASH_RECEIPT_ID
           AND acra.receipt_number LIKE 'IEX_%'
           AND acra.payment_trxn_extension_id IS NOT NULL
           AND itsa.initiator_extension_id = acra.payment_trxn_extension_id
           AND itsa.reqtype = 'ORAPMTREQ'
           AND itsa.instrtype = 'CREDITCARD'
           AND itsa.status = 0;

EXCEPTION
    WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
        insert into cx_log values('10 NODATAFOUND:' || dbms_utility.format_error_backtrace);
    WHEN OTHERS THEN 
        insert into cx_log values('20 Exception:' || dbms_utility.format_error_backtrace);
END; 


  IF vn_cash_receipt_id > 0 THEN    

   INSERT INTO cx_log values('Cash Receipt ID:' || :NEW.CASH_RECEIPT_ID
    || '--Customer TrxId:' || :NEW.APPLIED_CUSTOMER_TRX_ID
    || '--p_line_amount:' || :NEW.AMOUNT_APPLIED
    || '--p_tax:' || :NEW.TAX_APPLIED
    || '--p_freight:' || :NEW.FREIGHT_APPLIED);

  END IF;

END;
/

Table Structure: 
  ar_cash_receipts_all 
     - ar_receivable_applications_all
```

Issue is the last insert statement is invoked only once when there are multiple rows. A row in **ar_cash_receipts_all** should exist even before **trigger** is fired as the table is parent but for some reason the below query sql is not finding the 'vn_cash_receipt_id'.  Any ideas on why it's not finding for first rows?

Comment: The problem statement doesn't make sense.  Either the last row is the only one that meets the `when` criteria or the trigger is actually firing for each row that is inserted.  Perhaps your query isn't returning the data you expect.  Without a reproducible test case, it's very, very difficult for anyone to guess at why that would be.

Comment: @JustinCave Like you mentioned, my query is not finding the row in iby_trxn_summaries_all but if ar_receivable_applications_all table to get a new value as 'APP' it should have a row in iby_trxn_summaries_all table? Is there anyway we could trace why it is not doing it?

Comment: I'd just walk through the data that exists in the other tables and log what the trigger is seeing to figure out which table doesn't have the data you expect it to have.

Comment: @JustinCave Thank you. If that's  the case. Can you close the question?

Comment: I can vote to close.  You should have the ability to close your own question without waiting for additional votes.